# Data attributes on IE 9 and older not working on certain instances

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, custom-data-attribute

I have four buttons(divs). After I click on one of them the data attributes work and does not work for other three. I am setting two values(data-attributes) in click event handler and in callback to this event reading these value. It is working fine on Chrome and Firefox so the logic is fine. The weird thing is, once I go to developer tools in IE and use jquery to read the data-attributes. All four buttons start working.

Comment: `data-*` is not supported in IE9 (it behaves like any custom attribute in IE<11). jQuery creates a polyfill for the feature, that's why it works with jQuery.

Comment: What is a polyfill? Also I noticed that when I open the webpage on IE ony 2 button clicks work out of 4 and when I open developer tools and close it again all start working. Anyway to make them work directly on page load.